# List elements are not showing up after updating the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am having a listfragment showing some items,like the following

---

[image]

---

Now later on,on some event I just want to update this list with new items,Now if the number of new items in the new list are less than the old number of list items,then it is showing me the list like

---

[image]

---

**PROBLEM IS** : The empty list elements.The code  that is updating my list is

```
         myListView.invalidate();
         CustomAdapter adapter= new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), rowItems);
         notificationListView.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         //even tried the above piece of code in the runOnUiThread()
```

### Adapter Class

```
    import java.util.List;

import com.emaven.pcmhapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        List<RowItem> rowItem;

        CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItem) {
            this.context = context;
            this.rowItem = rowItem;


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return rowItem.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return rowItem.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

           // ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

            RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
            // setting the image resource and title
       //     imgIcon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
            txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());

            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

---

Comment: NobalG can you add your adapter code so easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code with Holder class:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);

            holder.txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());

            return convertView;

        }

class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTitle;
        }
```

Comment: what is special about the ViewHolder? Could you explain this please?

Comment: @nobalG Yes, see I have put one condition over there, so each time your rows will not inflated, it just checks if convertView!=null then it will directly take your data from ViewHolder.

Comment: @nobalG,ViewHolder is design pattern for ListView performance : http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: @nobalG you getting same issue still?

Comment: @pratt yess, no difference

Answer (score 0):

Define custom method to adapter which add in ListView :

Add multiple item :

```
public void addItem(List<RowItem> items){
   rowItem = new ArrayList<RowItem>(items);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Note :** Use [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) design pattern for ListView performance as per Below ans.

Comment: I am changing the adapter because the second list is completely different,say in one view I am setting the names of the person,and on updating lists I want the list to be populated with the names of their wives

Comment: Sorry for that,let me annotate this in another way. In your answer you are adding items to a currently existing adapter, but I want to set a completely new adapter for my listView

Comment: Having a completely new set of items

Comment: okay so simply remove if condition code from both method it show list with new set of items.

Comment: Yes it is updating the list,but my problem is:(see the images)